# Where are stored on file system Google Chrome passwords?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, passwords

Google Chrome saves user data of browser in a cache and in detail in this path (for windows):

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
```

I searched for a while through the folders but did not find anything about the browser-passwords.

**Question**

Does anyone know where are written on file system the saved browser-passwords?
And are browser-passwords saved encrypted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're in that folder, at %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Login Data

Yes, they are encrypted. You can view the plaintext passwords at: chrome://settings/passwords

You'll need the OS password to decrypt them.

Answer (score 1):

2020 update, I found them located in this directory:

```sh
~/Users/<yourUser>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default
```

Comment: What OS is that path referencing? macOS? I think the question is for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

it is in %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\ if anyone is wondering

Default represents the chrome user